# import fields from other table

Tags: ms-access

I am using access 2003.
Is it possible import selected fields into an existing table from other table?
I saw import table option but i didnt find any option for importing fields.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run a query for it.

```
insert into DestTable (Field1, Field2)  select Field1, Field2 from SourceTable
```

Comment: Hi binil,i did that previously but just checking whether any option is there through ms-acess design menu options like importing tables.

Comment: @ramu - you can create an Append query (should be an icon on the menu) and it will prompt you which table to insert your results.